# How to return an array and get the first element of it in one line in PHP?

Tags: php

this question is just for fun and maybe learning a PHP shorthand trick (if exists)
Let's assume that I have this code:

```
$item = $this->get_item($id);
$item = $this->prepare_items(array($item));
$item = $item[0];
```

By default, *prepare_items* function takes an array of items and return them with some modifications so if I want to call it on one item only I should push it into an array like above, but then I have to pull out the item from the array I created.

So is there a shorthand way to do this, like:

```
$item = $this->_prepare_items_output(array($item))[0];
// OR
$item = ($item = $this->_prepare_items_output(array($item)))[0];
```

Also if you have a link for a set of tips and tricks for PHP that would be great.

Comment: Is there any particular reason PHP *doesn't* support inline array index upon return value like this?  I don't know anything about compiler design, but it seems that plenty of other languages I have used support this.

Comment: I suspect a combination of initial laziness, followed by syntax rules that had to remain silly or break too much existing code (because that's a syntax error, not a semantic issue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `reset($array)` to reset the internal array position *and return the value of the first element*.

Comment: It's not very intuitive (if I would see that in the code, it would take me half a minute to understand what the hell it is for) but a valid answer.

Comment: this actually would do the job for this particular case, I'm gonna leave it for a day and then accept your answer as this question is meant for fun and not actually a problem.

Comment: I'm certainly not advocating its use in production code, but it's a nice curiosity ;-)

Comment: Very interesting...  Yes, I will never do this, but one of those dark corners of PHP I've never seen.  Interesting...

Comment: Yeah, according to the comments section in the documentation this would give unexpected results on associative arrays:http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php#96090   But still it works for this case :-)

Answer (score 2):

Nope, as far as I know, there is no way to do this in PHP.

What you *could* do is return an object of a class that has a method `getLine()`. With that, you could do

```
$item = $this->prepare_items(array($item))->getLine(0);
```

you could - I'm not saying it's necessarily always a good idea, but it's becoming more and more popular, probably influenced by jQuery's elegance - also store the results of `get_item` in the object, and have it return `$this` to allow for method chaining like so:

```
$item = $this->get_item($id)->prepare_items()->getLine(0);
```

Comment: I hate that about PHP. It doesn't seem like a particularly difficult thing to support...

Comment: ah thanks Pekka, that was fast! LOL
OK that is not necessary, by the way I have updated the question (last line).

Comment: hmm, nice addition..can you elaborate please..I'm using CI and the code is not actually like that, it's a model call:$this->Eb_model->get_item($id); which is returning $query->row_array();

Comment: @ifaour mmm, if this is following CI's coding standards, I wouldn't change it. For method chaining, every method would have to return its parent object (`return $this;`)

Answer (score 2):

### In PHP 5.4 this becomes an easy one-liner

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a
>   function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a
>   temporary variable.

```
$firstElement = getArray()[0];
```

where

```
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Taken from a slightly modified version of Example #7 from [the PHP manual pages (Arrays)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you can do this trick... for other indices, it gets uglier.

```
list($algo) = explode(':', $password);
```

I was looking for a more elegant answer but here we are :)