# How do I get the value in a single element array in one line without strict warnings in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, arrays

Given a function which returns an array;

```
function return_me_an_array() {
  return array('my_value');
}
```

How can I call it and get a single value (whether, first, last or only) from the array in an elegant fashion (yes I know this is PHP!)

If I do this

```
$var = reset(return_me_an_array());
```

I get the following PHP strict error:

> Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference

Likewise each of these give the same warning.

```
$var = array_shift(return_me_an_array());
$var = array_pop(return_me_an_array());
```

I know I can do this:

```
$temp = return_me_an_array();
$var = $reset($temp);
```

But *having* to do it over two statements is pretty horrible.

Is there a good way to do this?

On the face of it this is similar to [How to return an array and get the first element of it in one line in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286734/how-to-return-an-array-and-get-the-first-element-of-it-in-one-line-in-php) but the accepted answer uses `reset` - so I think this is different; I'm either looking for a solution that doesn't give strict warnings, or to be told what I want is impossible.

I'm also aware the PHP 5.4 has introduced array dereferencing (e.g. `return_me_an_array()[0]`) but alas I am currently using 5.3.

**Edit after being closed**: How is this too localized? This is a general question about how to write elegant PHP. Or is it the case that so few people care about elegant PHP it is "an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet"?

Comment: I guess you could just write a custom function for it...

Comment: I think you are out of luck with this one. It is php ..

Comment: I believe that those functions in PHP are known as "constructs" which do not accept variable functions if I remember right...due to the reference usage of it

Comment: @Sammaye Nope, it's just that they take their arguments by reference. It has nothing to do with language constructs.

Comment: @deceze Ah OK I remember reading somewhere it was a construct but that was prolly another function.

Comment: IMO, there is no point in trying to come up with some fancy one-liner. Assign to temp var, like everyone else does, too. or upgrade to 5.4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parentheses altering semantics of function call result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6726589/367456) and [Strict standards error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6726219/367456)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
$var = current(return_me_an_array());
```

Demo: http://3v4l.org/Ruj5e

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php

Comment: How does this solve the problem? EDIT: using current() won't solve it either, it requires a pass by reference

Comment: As far as I know current() just returns the item the array pointer is pointing at. It does not change the array so it can accept a direct array as returned by a function.

Comment: Confirmed it does work strangely, though the documentation is wrong: `current ( array &$array )` since it should pass as reference which means this should not function right, but it does.

Comment: This seems to work for me and http://3v4l.org/Ruj5e confirms that. Are there any reasons not to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Define your own array methods for that purpose:

```
function my_reset($array)
{
    return reset($array);
}

echo my_reset(return_me_an_array());
```

**UPD:**

There is even more elegant way, check [Returning References](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) manual

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$var = array_shift($var = return_me_an_array());
```

[Link to codepad](http://codepad.org/cKP73JjF)

Comment: I'm not actually sure that works and I'm too lazy to find out. Can you post a proof on codepad.org?

Comment: Nope it doesn't, just tested it.

Comment: @deceze : Hahaha, lazy person. i have checked this on my localhost but still i will post you a link for codepad

Comment: Did you do that on php 5.3? I use http://codepad.viper-7.com and it doesn't work on php 5.3-dev

Comment: ya i didnt do that on php 5.3 or above, it gives error. lemme check another solution

Answer (score 0):

Ok can't he just supress the error? Or is that not elegant enough?

`$var = @reset(return_me_an_array());`

Or like shared at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6726277/881551

`$var = reset( ( return_me_an_array() ) );`

Both tested and work fine for the purpose of circumventing the strict notice which is what is essentially being asked.